# why windows installer doesn't use my EmbeddedUIHandler when it is dependent to other DLLs?

Tags: c, dll, windows-installer, installshield

I'm trying to handle all of User Interfaces (UI) dialogs in `.msi` installing pakage, with `EmbeddedUIHandler` to do this I have created a `setupui.dll` which contains three methods: `InitializeEmbeddedUI, ShutdownEmbeddedUI, EmbeddedUIHandler`, and put it inside of `MsiEmbeddedUI` table (using installshield) and it worked just fine.

The problem is when `setupui.dll` is dependent to other external DLLs, this time windows installer won't use my dll and it uses default ui, I have added other DLL dependencies with Installshield as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain of what Windows Installer allows here. There are, however, three things that jump out at me as things to look into:

- The [MsiEmbeddedUI table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736317.aspx)'s Attributes column should probably have a 3 for SetupUI.dll (as it does), and 0 for the rest. Per the docs, the 2 bit is ignored if the 1 bit isn't present, but all the other files are better described as "It may be a resource used by the user interface."
- The verbose log: does it indicate what's going on? Does it show a failure loading SetupUI.dll that provides a useful error code (hint: file not found probably refers to a dependency)? Does it indicate it didn't even try to load your DLL? Look for lines with `EEUI`, at least in the successful case.
- If Windows Installer does attempt to load SetupUI.dll, how far does it get? If it gets far enough for you to run some code and, say, show a message box, what files are already extracted at that point? If the dependencies are extracted, can you ensure that its directory is on the DLL path via SetDllDirectory or AddDllDirectory? If the dependencies are not extracted, are they present at a later point so approches like delay loading could help?

For the third point, Process Monitor may help you diagnose what's going on if you can't get a message box in there, but it will probably be less clear. Alternately, using Loader Snaps and Debug View might get you a related set of information, but it may be drowned in additional noise.